# How to know when exception is throwned in destructor in php

Tags: php, class, exception, try-catch, destructor

Let say I have some classes to work with MVC. The base class for controller have a constructor and destructor.

```
class BaseController {
    public function __construct() {
        ob_start();

    }

    # Some code here.

    public function __destruct() {
        if(!error_get_last()) {
            if(!$this->doNotOutputBuffer) {
                $controllerContent = ob_get_contents();
                ob_clean();
                $this->_template->render($this->_appinfo['directory'], $this->templateOptions, $controllerContent);
            } else {
                $this->_template->render($this->_appinfo['directory'], $this->templateOptions);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note the existence of ob_star() and ob_clean() on each functions, it's supposed to pass the view data to the template class to render the views with the template. When an exceptions is throwed I catch the error in a "TryCatch" block outside of LoginController, but the destructor is always called and error_get_last() function returns NULL, anyway the view is going to be loaded even if there's an error.

```
class LoginController extends BaseController{

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function main() {    
        throw new Exception("Error Fatal...");
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        parent::__destruct();
    }

}
```

How I can know when an exception occurs to not show the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add flag and wrap method.

```
class LoginController extends BaseController{

    private $_is_throwed = false;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function main() {
        try{
            $this->_main();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_is_throwed = true;
            throw $e;
        }
    }

    private function _main() {
        throw new Exception("Error Fatal...");
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        if (!$this->_is_throwed) {
            parent::__destruct();
        } else {
            ob_clean();
        }
    }

}
```

P.S. But be careful with using logic in destructs, it can cause troubles.